# Eloquent ORM Relationships - is the default "no relationship"?

Tags: orm, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I'm building an application to keep travel booking information, and wanted to ask about a little thing before I embark on using Laravels ORM.

Say a group of travellers have booked a ticket, that's great. They would also like to buy hotel bookings from us as well. Buying hotel bookings is an option, groups don't have to buy hotel bookings.

So I have the following set up as my database:

```
Table Group:
Group_ID
Name
etc

Table Hotel_Bookings:
Group_ID
Hotel name
Number of people
Number of rooms
Type of rooms
etc
```

I know I can define a relationship such as:

```
class Group extends Eloquent {

    public function hotel_bookings()
    {
      return $this->hasOne('hotel_bookings');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Hotel_bookings extends Eloquent {

    public function group()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('group');
    }
}
```

But what if a group doesn't decide to book a hotel with us? In that case there would be no hotel booking row associated with that group in the hotel_bookings table. Would the ORM be aware of there being no such row in the table, and would it spit out an error or do nothing?

Is a one to one relationship where there is one row in the first table related to one row in the second?

Hopefully you can tell that I'm new to ORMs, I'd like to know more about this if it would make my database querying life easier from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "hasOne" or "hasMany" doesn't necessary mean you *must* have related data, it just means you *can*.

In this case, entries in your `Group` table would work fine whether there's a `Hotel_booking` entry attached to that entry or not.

`Hotel_booking`, on the other hand, is a "belongsTo".  Assuming your database schema reflects this relationship as expected, a `Hotel_booking` entry *would* require a related `Group` entry.

Comment: yes that's correct, a hotel booking should have a group associated with it, otherwise its a booking for nobody (maybe ghosts) :). Thank you, you answered my question of whether a hasOne relationship must have related data or not

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're saying you have a Group that can have an optional Hotel_bookings (check Laravel naming conventions, use HotelBooking or Hotelbooking). The way that you've set up your relationships will not cause any errors. The ORM doesn't force any sort of relationship you should be setting that in your migration.

```
Schema::table(...function(Blueprint $table)
{
    ...
    $table->integer('group_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('group_id')->references('id')->on('groups');
```

This is what enforces that a HotelBooking must belong to a Group. Eloquent doesn't automatically make the query for you to retrieve a Group's HotelBooking, it requires that you do it using something like:

```
$group = Group::with('hotel_bookings')->first();
```

This will not throw errors either, $group->hotel_bookings will simply be empty.

Comment: sorry I'm in a bit of a dilemma, cmallard answered my question more directly so I've gratefully accepted his answer. I hope you don't mind, and I absolutely value your help, thank you!

Comment: No worries, just here to pass the time.